# Add gitignore for node_module failed

Tags: git

I created a `.gitignore` file and within it I put `"node_modules"`. But when I run `git status` it still shows my `node_modules` folder as untracked file. What's wrong?

Comment: Did you track the node_modules before adding it to .gitignore?

Comment: @ThomasBormans I do git init before I do npm init of course.

Comment: @NicholeA.Miler That doesn't answer the question: `git init` has nothing to do with *tracking* files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to ignore a folder, make sure to add a trailing slash in your `.gitignore` line:

```
node_modules/
```

(not `"node_modules"` with quotes)

If you still see untracked files, check also the rules with:

```
git check-ignore -v -- node_modules
```

Make sure the `.gitignore` is placed at the same level or above the folder which container `node_modules`.
Make sure the .gitignore name is correct (case, and no trailing space like '`.gitgignore`')

Comment: now I change it to `node_modules/`, and do git status, it's there still.

Comment: @NicholeA.Miler No problem, I have edited the answer to make that clear.